# vcpkg libxlsxwriter fails, something to do with libzip / minizip

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2022, vcpkg, libxlsxwriter

Trying to build libxlsxwriter with vcpkg and a manifest file but I keep getting this error:

```
Could not find a package configuration file provided by "MINIZIP" with any
  of the following names:

    unofficial-minizipConfig.cmake
    unofficial-minizip-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "MINIZIP" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "MINIZIP_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "MINIZIP" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:228 (find_package)
```

The strange thing is that it is already installed in vcpkg:

D:\dev\vcpkg>vcpkg update
Using local portfile versions. To update the local portfiles, use `git pull`.
No packages need updating.

```
D:\dev\vcpkg>vcpkg list
http-parser:x64-windows                           2.9.4#3             HTTP Parser.
libgit2:x64-windows                               1.6.4#1             A C library implementing the Git core methods wi...
libgit2[pcre]:x64-windows                                             Build against external libpcre
libgit2[ssh]:x64-windows                                              SSH support via libssh2
libgit2[ssl]:x64-windows                                              Default SSL backend
libgit2[winhttp]:x64-windows                                          SSL support (WinHTTP)
libssh2:x64-windows                               1.11.0#1            libssh2 is a client-side C library implementing ...
libssh2[openssl]:x64-windows                                          Use the openssl crypto backend
libssh2[zlib]:x64-windows                                             Use compression via zlib
libxlsxwriter:x64-windows                         1.1.5#2             Libxlsxwriter is a C library that can be used to...
minizip:x64-windows                               1.3.1               Minizip zip file manipulation library
openssl:x64-windows                               3.2.1               OpenSSL is an open source project that provides ...
pcre:x64-windows                                  8.45#5              Perl Compatible Regular Expressions
sqlite3:x64-windows                               3.45.0              SQLite is a software library that implements a s...
sqlite3[json1]:x64-windows                                            Enable JSON functionality for sqlite3
vcpkg-cmake-config:x64-windows                    2022-02-06#1
vcpkg-cmake-get-vars:x64-windows                  2023-12-31
vcpkg-cmake:x64-windows                           2023-05-04
vcpkg-gn:x64-windows                              2021-11-16#3        https://gn.googlesource.com/gn/+/4aa9bdfa05b688c...
vcpkg-tool-gn:x64-windows                         2022-04-16#1        GN build system
vcpkg-tool-lessmsi:x64-windows                    1.10.0#1            This is a utility with a graphical user interfac...
vcpkg-tool-python2:x64-windows                    2.7.18#1            Python 2
zlib:x64-windows                                  1.3.1               A compression library
```

Why vcpkg does not use the installed version when I use it in manifest mode?

Any idea how to bypass the zip problem in libxlsxwriter when using it with vcpkg?